# How to open db.sqlite in Aloha Editor?

Tags: sqlite, aloha-editor

I'm using [Aloha Editor](http://www.aloha-editor.org/) and I'm able to save/edit content without any problem.

Editor saves content in SQLite database (db.sqlite). I know where the file is and I see that's getting bigger while I'm adding more text to it.

But when I transfer that fille using filezilla to local computer and I open in notepad I see only:

> ** This file contains an SQLite 2.1 database **

I've tried to use few programs but it always says that database that unable to open.

The programs I've tried: Sqliteman-1.2.2 and sqlitebrowser_200_b1_win.

Comment: Sorry I meant opened file in my code editor but just checked in notepad now and there a lot SQL code.

Comment: I've tried several programs which claims to open SQLite 2.1 but only this one worked: [link]http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/files/sqlitebrowser/1.1/

Comment: I am trying to get my aloha editor to save to a db could you show me how you did yours?